# Continuously sending sensor data to SignalR hub

Tags: c#, signalr, uwp, raspberry-pi2, windowsiot

I'm running Windows IoT on a Raspberry Pi.

After I turn on my Raspberry Pi and Windows IoT starts up, I want to automatically begin reading sensor data from a serial port continuously, and also send the data to a SignalR server/hub continuously. I don't need any UI.

I'm new at UWP apps. Is it best practice to use a headless background task for doing it? But how can I make sure, that the data reading and sending interval is not too long (~1-20ms)? Because I want to use a SignalR client to send the data near real-time.

Answer (score 0):

First you should take care of the size of the package. 
Maybe you should also think about using Azure IoT Hub. Azure IoT Hub is build exactly for scenerios like yours, receiving extrem high amount of sensor data in near real time from many devices. And it is highly scalable, and can be used from any client platform.

Here you find documentation, backgrounds and samples: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/iot-hub/